# R openxlsx writeFormula gives a corrupted file

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am trying to overwrite an Excel file with some new data.

My new data looks like this

```
new_data <- structure(list(date=c(1:30),var1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), var2 = c("=B13-B12", 
"=B14-B13", "=B15-B14", "=B16-B15", "=B17-B16", "=B18-B17", "=B19-B18", 
"=B20-B19", "=B21-B20", "=B22-B21", "=B23-B22", "=B24-B23", "=B25-B24", 
"=B26-B25", "=B27-B26", "=B28-B27", "=B29-B28", "=B30-B29", "=B31-B30", 
"=B32-B31", "=B33-B32", "=B34-B33", "=B35-B34", "=B36-B35", "=B37-B36", 
"=B38-B37", "=B39-B38", "=B40-B39", "=B41-B40", "=B42-B41")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My dataset has more columns but those are the ones I identified as the ones messing up the file, specifically the var2 one.

Then I just turn my data from wide to long so I can group the data and write all columns with `group_map`.

```
update <- new_data %>%
                mutate_if(is.numeric,as.character) %>%
                pivot_longer(-date,
                             names_to = "var",
                             values_to = "value") %>% 
                select(var,value) %>% 
                mutate(col=c(1:2))
```

(NAs are actually in a numeric column, that is why I need to change numeric to character -plus I have more numeric columns within my dataset)

This is how I am writing my data into the excel file.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook(paste(path,"file.xlsx",sep='/'))

update %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  group_map(~writeFormula(wb=wb, sheet ="FirstSheet", x=.x$value,
                          startCol=.x$col,startRow=13))
saveWorkbook(wb,paste(path,"new_file.xlsx",sep='/'),overwrite = TRUE)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I guess it is due to the `NA` values since I have other columns coded the exact same way and they seem to be working just fine (with some I get a warning saying that the formula differs from the ones around them but I can live with that).

How should I manage this NA values? (they need to remain as missing values, for example a zero would be incorrect)

I tried changing them to empty strings (`new_data[is.na(new_data)]<-""`) before writing them into the file but the problem is still there.

Note: The message I get when I try to open the file is that it needs to be repaired. If I do repair it, it looks fine but I cannot reopen it again once closed.

Comment: When I run your code for update, it says: `✖ Column `date` doesn't exist.
`.

Comment: The date error is fixed, but now it says that it can't find the variables `variable` and `cantidad` in your update code.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm sorry, English is not my native language and I tried to change spanish variable names to English so it would be more readable but I forgot about those, thank you so much for pointing them out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for me as expected: non-missing formulas are written, `NA`'s are left blank. No corrupted message from Excel.

```
update_df <- new_data %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,as.character) %>%
  pivot_longer(-date,
               names_to = "var",
               values_to = "value") %>% 
  select(var,value) %>% 
  mutate(col=3)



library(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook(paste("file.xlsx"))
  # group_by(var) %>% # filter(is.na(value)) %>% 
  purrr::map(updatedf,.f= ~ writeFormula(wb, x= updatedf$value, sheet=1, startCol = c(1), startRow = 1))
saveWorkbook(wb,"new_file.xlsx",overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Check if:

- Is `file.xlsx` corrupted? What happens if you load it and write it without any modifications, can you open `file.xlsx` and `new_file.xlsx` then without a warning?
- Can you reproduce the above solution by using a blank `file.xlsx`? If you still see corruption in `new_file.xlsx` after starting from a blank `file.xlsx`, this would indicate an issue with either `excel` or `openxlsx`.
- What version of `Excel`, `R` and `openxlsx` are you running?

My config:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
openxlsx_4.2.5
Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20166) 32-bit
```

---

**EDIT** After discussion, the problem might come from overwriting existing formulas.

- Try to write the same formulas into other cells in your excel file where you're sure they won't interfere
- Try deleting existing content before writing with something like:

`deleteData(wb, sheet = 1,cols = unique(update_df$col), rows = 1:60, gridExpand = TRUE)`

Comment: It still gives out a warning message saying that the file needs to be repaired. After agreeing to repair the file the message is "Registers removed: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part" (I'm sorry if it doesn't sound right I'm translating it). `R version 4.2.1`  -  `openxlsx version 4.2.5`  -  `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2207 build 16.0.15427.20182) 64-bits`

Comment: what happens when you start from a blank `file.xlsx`?

Comment: What do you mean? Reading a blank file? I haven't tried but the thing is, doing the exact same thing in that same file works perfectly for other columns and that is what's baffling me. Same code on other files also does the job with no problem.

Comment: exactly: by using a blank file, we're debugging. which means we're trying to find out whether the bug comes from the original file, the new formulas, or an incompatibility between both.

Comment: I tried writing into a new blank file and it works. Empty column and next to it a "0" column with the formula written.

Comment: Therefore, the problem resides in the original file. are you trying to overwrite existing formulas in `file.xlsx`, creating a circular ref in any way?

Comment: The original file does have formulas already written in those cells, but they are the same ones I'm writing again (I do this because I update multiple excel files at once and not all of them have the formula written). With other columns it is the same but they aren't trying to apply a formula to "NA"s, that is why I thought "NA"s were the issue here.

Comment: i'd bet this is where the problem comes from. see edits for new debugging steps according to this new information

Comment: I tried what you suggested and writing the formula column in a different one where there's nothing already there works perfect! But then I try the second part (deleting things off) and it breaks the whole file. So much so that the whole file ends up blank (don't worry I'm working with a copy in cas something like thiss happened). This is the new message excel gives when opening it after deleting+writing: "Part replaced: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part with XML error.  The name of the end of element label must match the initial label element type. Line 1, column 149366." (and others like this)

Comment: I'll keep trying the delete function, cause I've never used before and maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: okay. don't hesitate to upvote / accept answers you're finding useful

Comment: I figured out what was wrong when I tried `deleteData` and now everything is completely solved! You even solved me another minor issue I hadn't had the chance to start trying to solve. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I can't actually give you the bounty until one hour from now but the moment I can I will so very gladly do it don't worry about it :)

Comment: it's okay ;) happy to help